# XAMPP apache setup on Windows to run .py Python files : ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, python, php, cgi

I've got my installation of the newest XAMPP version (w/PHP 7.2.2) setup and running apache just fine on my Windows 10 laptop for my PHP programming class. I was able to get CGI working to run .py files correctly in the browser window, using the option +ExecCGI and adding .py to the AddHandler line in the /XAMPP/apache/conf/httpd.conf.

Normally the first two lines need to look like this with CGI in order for the .py file to run correctly:

```
#!C:/Python/Python36_x86/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
```

However, after reading Apache2.4 documentation for ScriptInterpreterSource: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#scriptinterpretersource

I added the correct registry key mentioned in the documentation along with the line:

```
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

to my /XAMPP/apache/conf/httpd.conf

and was able to run my Python script without those first two lines. However, it still requires an extra print() statement on the first line (or print('\n') ).

===========================================================================

MY QUESTION:

Is there any way at all to get around needing the print/newline statement on the first line of the Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way at all to get around needing the print/newline statement on the first line of the Python script?

Probably not... at least not for using Python via CGI.

For a given CGI script (not just those in Python), the language-equivalent of this "blank line" (`CRLF`) is needed at the start of any data returned to the browser. And while Apache grabs the interpreter path and value for the `Content-type` header from the registry, it appears not to include this line.

> It still requires an extra `print()` statement on the first line (or `print('\n')` ).

For clarity, in case there is any confusion, it simply has to be the first line of text you output (if any) from your script e.g.:

```
# Print our Python version

import sys

version = sys.version_info
full_version = str(version.major) + '.' + str(version.minor) + '.' + str(version.micro)

# 8000 more lines that don't include print()...

# === Our first line(s) of text output ===
# print ('Content-type: text/html')
print ('')

print ('Python Version: ', full_version)
```

---

*Note (for everyone else): If you don't have everything registered like OP, you still need a hash-bang such as `!# python` as your first line and should uncomment `print ('Content-type: text/html')`.*

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not allowed to mark it or anything since I am a new member with <15 rep.

Comment: No worries. You're welcome. =)

Comment: I was finally able to accept your answer... over 2 years later, lol. Thanks again!

Comment: Lol Not a problem at all! Thanks. =)